# What's the best way to install the GD graphics library for Nagios?

Tags: graphics, png, nagios3

While trying to install Nagios 3.2.3, I ran their ./configure script and got these errors:

```
checking for main in -liconv... no
checking for gdImagePng in -lgd (order 1)... no
checking for gdImagePng in -lgd (order 2)... no
checking for gdImagePng in -lgd (order 3)... no
checking for gdImagePng in -lgd (order 4)... no


*** GD, PNG, and/or JPEG libraries could not be located... *********

Boutell's GD library is required to compile the statusmap, trends
and histogram CGIs.  Get it from http://www.boutell.com/gd/, compile
it, and use the --with-gd-lib and --with-gd-inc arguments to specify
the locations of the GD library and include files.

NOTE: In addition to the gd-devel library, you'll also need to make
      sure you have the png-devel and jpeg-devel libraries installed
      on your system.

NOTE: After you install the necessary libraries on your system:
      1. Make sure /etc/ld.so.conf has an entry for the directory in
         which the GD, PNG, and JPEG libraries are installed.
      2. Run 'ldconfig' to update the run-time linker options.
      3. Run 'make clean' in the Nagios distribution to clean out
         any old references to your previous compile.
      4. Rerun the configure script.

NOTE: If you can't get the configure script to recognize the GD libs
      on your system, get over it and move on to other things.  The
      CGIs that use the GD libs are just a small part of the entire
      Nagios package.  Get everything else working first and then
      revisit the problem.  Make sure to check the nagios-users
      mailing list archives for possible solutions to GD library
      problems when you resume your troubleshooting.

********************************************************************
```

Which package do I want?  libgd2-xpm-dev? libgd2-noxpm-dev? php5-gd?  I'm not looking to do any image processing myself - I just want to get Nagios working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the quickstart guide on [nagios' website](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/quickstart-ubuntu.html), you'll notice that the guide for Ubuntu 7.10 and later asks you to install `libgd2-xpm-dev` with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgd2-xpm-dev
```

That should do it for ya!  Of course you could always follow the Ubuntu Server guide and [install the nagios packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/nagios.html) instead of building it yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  The quickstart guide says "With Ubuntu 7.10" and doesn't mention the "later" part, which was what confused me since 7.10 was a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

I used commands like this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Voting up, this worked for me. I'm not sure if you need to install both libgd2-xpm-dev and do the above, but I did all 3 and it works now.